# how to run multiple projects in visual studio simultaneously

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to get my main project and my API to run along side each other in Visual Studio 2015. The method that usually works is: start my main project, then right-click on API project, go to Debug, select Start New Instance. But that doesn't always work. It sometimes crashes on me with an exception saying: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: httpContext".

What is the proper procedure for running more than one project at once from the same Visual Studio instance?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that both your projects are in the same solution: right click the **Solution**, click **"Set Startup Projects"**, then select **"Multiple Startup Projects"** and indicate the ones you want to start when you click **"Run"**.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Property form (Right click on Solution and select "Properties" in the context menu) there will be options allowing you to manage the startup project(s). You can configure:

- Currently selected project
- Specific project by name
- A list of projects in the solution (you can change the order in which they are started as well).